# Check value of nested json response

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I want to get the close time from my google places json response depending on what the current day is. This line of code gives me a 0-6 value for the current day of the week.

```
NSString *dayOfWeek = [myFormatter stringFromDate:today];
```

I have an NSArray to store the results of the google places response.

```
NSArray* periods= [[place objectForKey:@"opening_hours"]objectForKey:@"periods"];
```

The json response that is in the periods array looks like this.

```
Period RESULT (
        {
        close =         {
            day = 0;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 0;
            time = 1100;
        };
    },
        {
        close =         {
            day = 1;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 1;
            time = 1100;
        };
    },
        {
        close =         {
            day = 2;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 2;
            time = 1100;
        };
    },
        {
        close =         {
            day = 3;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 3;
            time = 1100;
        };
    },
        {
        close =         {
            day = 4;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 4;
            time = 1100;
        };
    },
        {
        close =         {
            day = 5;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 5;
            time = 1100;
        };
    },
        {
        close =         {
            day = 6;
            time = 2300;
        };
        open =         {
            day = 6;
            time = 1100;
        };
    }
)
```

How do I use my dayOfWeek value to check the periods array for the correct close.time?

Comment: Actually, what you have above is not JSON, but rather the "description" (NSLog) of an NSArray containing the deserialized JSON.  The array contains NSDictionarys, and each NSDictionary in the array contains two more NSDictionarys.  If you understand how to program at all it should be a simple matter to loop through the array, look at each entry, and do the checks you want.  (What have you tried?)

Comment: (If you can't figure this out on your own you need to set aside Objective-C for awhile and do more education with Java or some such.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the array contains NSDictionarys, and I understand that I need to learn more - in process. My hope was to ask a question here to aid in that process. Most of what I've tried revolves around using something like if (![periods containsObject:dayOfWeek]) [periods addObject:valueForKeyPath:@"close.time"];

Comment: Hint:  Write a loop.  Extract each array element.  NSLog it.  Then decide what to do with it.  Repeat.  This is what I do when dealing with complex JSON (which this of course is not, but the process is still valid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( NSDictionary *d in periods ){
  NSInteger day = [[[d objectForKey:@"close"] objectForKey:@"day"] integerValue];

  if( day == [dayOfWeek integerValue] ){
    return [[[d objectForKey:@"close"] objectForKey:@"time"] integerValue];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do this would be to leverage [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) and [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"close.day = %@", dayOfWeek];
NSArray *output = [periods filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSNumber *closingTime = [output.lastObject valueForKeyPath:@"close.time"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution but I'm getting (null) for closingTime, which upon further checking is because the output array is empty even though the response contains objects that should be in that array.

Comment: Hmm, I checked this with an array constructed based on your posted JSON.

Comment: If the type of day is an NSNumber then you'll need to change the predicate to `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"close.day = %d", dayOfWeek.intValue];`